# How to convert $\ kWh/m^2 $ to $\ Joule/kg$

Tags: physics, unit-of-measure

How to convert $$\ kWh/m^2$$ to $$\  Joule/kg$$

I want to compare the radiation produced by the sun over a location (where I live in, measured in $\ kWh/m^2$),  to the radiation a person gets from a CT scan in the unit sieverts (Sv, whose equivalence  is $\ Joule/kg $).

Thus you may want to know what produces more radiation:
The Global Horizontal Sun Radiation over Vilnius versus the radiation produced by a regular nose CT scan (which is in Sieverts)

For instance, you may get the solar radiation over a location data from
https://globalsolaratlas.info/?c=-28.56667,-70.75,3&s=-28.56667,-70.75
But I don't know how to compare both magnitudes

I need it for a research I am working on.
Thank you.

Comment: You multiply and divide by appropriate quantities. I'm not really sure what confuses you here.

Comment: Please, may you be more specific? I would thank that

Comment: If memory serves me right, you don't, unless you are in some non-IS measure system where $m^2kg^{-1}$ is a constant.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=kWh%2Fm%5E2+to+J%2Fkg

Answer (score 1):

These two units don't match up.

You have a density of energy in $kWh = \frac{1000}{3600} Joule$ per square meter.

And you have a mass density of energy in Joule.

So you can't convert from one to another unless you had more information.

Also, this is probably more appropriated in the physics SE.

Comment: I am trying to compare the sun irradiation (in $\ kWh/m^2$) to the radiation I may get by, for instance, taking a CT scan (in $\ Joule/kg$)

Comment: Joule per kilograms of what? What is the mass referential associated with your variable in Joule/kg. Assuming you can guess the mass $m$ and a surface $S$; dimensional analysis gives: $\frac{kWh}{S} = \frac{1000}{3600 \cdot m} Joule$.

Comment: I have just added more information about my question

Comment: Thank you all for your comments